# phonegap NSInternalInconsistencyException error in config.xml

Tags: cordova

I am running my phonegap app on xcode simulator. It gives me the exception below for IOS6.1. Both 7.0 and 7.1 are ok.

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'config.xml parse error line 47 col 21'

The error line in config.xml is

```
<gap:plugin name="nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing" />
```

However, if I comment out it, error will fall to the next line , i.e.

```
<gap:plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification" />
```

Issue is gone only after I comment out all

```
<!--<gap:plugin name="nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing" /> -->
<!--<gap:plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification" /> -->
 <!--   <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" /> -->
```

Any idea?

Regards
Hammer

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause, it was missing

xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"

But it is strange that iOS 7 and 7.1 do not throw any exception.